# Tableview header view issue in ios 11

Tags: swift, tableview, ios11

I am facing an issue in viewForHeaderInSection function. in ios 10 it's working fine but in ios 11 it's create duplicate view on each reloading of tableview means it's means dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView is not working.

I follow the process for adding viewForHeaderInSection.
first i register nib for custom header view witch is sub class of  UITableViewHeaderFooterView

```
 self.tblView.register(UINib(nibName: "CommentShotringHeader", bundle: nil), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "CommentShotringHeader")
```

And here is my UITableViewDelegate method is

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 45.0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let viewHeader = self.tblView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "CommentShotringHeader") as! CommentShotringHeader
    return viewHeader
}
```

It's seams like issue in IOS 11 or any changes in this method i have searched for it but still i am not getting proper solution .

if any one also facing the same issue. and found any solution for this. please suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same issue here. Did you find the cause?

Comment: No, I didn't get

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `estimatedSectionHeaderHeight` on iOS11 (tested up to 11.3). It can cause multiple issues one which you is what you explained.

If you can pre-calculate the height use

`self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 40;`

instead of

`self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 40;`

otherwise override delegate method:

```
// Swift
public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    // return calculated height
}

// Obj-c
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // return calculated height
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @mojtaba can you please explain why this is happening in new ios version. because if I want to set dynamic height of header with autolayout how can I achieve.

Comment: @Rakesh I already reported it to Apple, one day it will get fixed. We couldn't get to work with auto layout.

Comment: @Rakesh Please mark the question as answered if it solved your issue